# How to get id of specific record in a table - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, toggle

I am trying to change the value of the is_public column in the  MySQL article table using a toggle switch.
if I  wrap the input(the toggle) inside  to get record's id using $_GET method for making necessary changes in the articles.php then it does not fetch data of is_public into the toggle. is there any other way to get the id of a specific record?

[screenshot of the article list table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UilN5.png)

this is all-articles.php code:

```
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">                                                                    
                         <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Abstract</th>
                            <th>category</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Action</th> 
                            <th>Publish</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                       <?php foreach($articles as $key => $article): ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $key+1 ?></td> 
                            <td><?php echo $article['title'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $article['author_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $article['abstract'] ?></td> 
                            <td><?php echo $article['category_id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $article['entry_date'] ?></td>
                            <td>
                              <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Show</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button> 
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td> 

                                <form action="all-articles.php" method="post">
                                <label class="custom-toggle">
                                  <?php if($article['is_public']): ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox" checked name="check">
                                  <?php else: ?>
                                    <input type="checkbox"  name="uncheck">
                                  <?php endif; ?>
                                    <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
                                </label> 
                                </form> 
                            </td>
                        </tr> 


                       <?php endforeach; ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Comment: You need to be a little more clear as what are you trying to do ?? do you want to be able to click on certain article and be able to edit it in some other page ??\

Comment: @alithedeveloper I want to change the value in the is_public column in the MySQL article table, I mean when toggle is switched on, the value in the is_public change to 1 and if it is switched off value should change to 0. to do this I need to get the id of that specific row/record.

Comment: Does the articles table include a [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) (e.g. `id`)?

Comment: @showdev yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You can send the article id in your form and then listen to it and do what you want with it. So,

```
// As you are already in foreach loop so,
 <form action="all-articles.php" method="post">
    <label class="custom-toggle">
      <?php if($article['is_public']): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="published" value="<?php echo $article['id']; ?>>
       <?php else: ?>
         <input type="checkbox"  name="published" value="<?php echo $article['id']; ?>>
       <?php endif; ?>
         <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
      </label> 
  </form>
```

Then in your `/all-articles.php` check for the `$_POST['check']` which should give `article id`. query your database with that id and toggle the `is_public` column

Another way would be to send a hidden field, some thing like

```
// As you are already in foreach loop so,
 <form action="all-articles.php" method="post">
    <label class="custom-toggle">
      <?php if($article['is_public']): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" checked name="published" value="<?php echo $article['id']; ?>>
        <input type="hidden" name="is_published" value="yes"> or 1
       <?php else: ?>
         <input type="hidden" name="is_published" value="no"> or 0
         <input type="checkbox"  name="published" value="<?php echo $article['id']; ?>>
       <?php endif; ?>
         <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
      </label> 
  </form>
```